# Select statement with Binary field

Tags: mysql, binary, binary-data

I'm trying to select all the data from a table by identifying the userID stored as a SMALLINT and a passwordTest stored as  BINARY(32). Here is the query I used to make the table :

```
{   {CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`User` 
(`UserID` SMALLINT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`firstname` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`lastname` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`passwordTest` BINARY(32) NOT NULL,
`registration_date` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `password_UNIQUE` (`passwordTest` ASC));}
```

Here is the query I used to insert test values into the table :

```
{INSERT INTO USER (firstname, lastname, passwordTest)
VALUES('Test','1','password');}
```

Here is my SQL query that doesn't work :

```
{USE test;
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE userID = '00001' AND passwordTest = 'password';}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you define password column as binary, you have to convert the password into binary in the where clause. This works in mysql5.6

`Select *
  From User
 Where UserID = '00001' 
  and passwordTest = cast('password' as BINARY(32))`

Comment: thanks! 
that also works:
`cast(0x914DC9....FC4DDA4 as BINARY(32))`